# How to add extra information to a hash code?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashcode

Given an array of bytes, there are several well-known good algorithms for calculating a hash code, such as FNV or MD5. (Not talking about cryptography here, just general purpose hash codes.)

Suppose what you have is an array of bytes plus one extra piece of information, a small integer (which is not located next to the array in memory), and you want a hash code based on the whole lot. What's the best way to do this? For example, one could take the hash code of the array and add it to the small integer, or exclusive-or them. But is there a better way?

Comment: Define 'better'. As long as we have no information about the application specific characteristics of your data XOR the values is a fast and well understood approach.

Comment: Just encode the "extra" information as bytes and append them to the hashed data.

Answer (score 2):

I think, more easiest and efficient way - just init "hash" accumulator with your small value, and thereafter compute hash by ordinary way.
Following example illustrates my approach, where we compute hash from int and C-style string:

```
uint32_t hash(const char *str, uint32_t x) {
  char c;
  while((c = *str++) != 0)
      x = ((x << 5) | (x >> (32 - 5))) + c;
  return x ^ (x >> 16);
}
```